# What does it mean when a journal is asking for declarations?

Tags: publications, phd, journals, paper-submission

I want to submit my first paper as a Ph.D. student to [this](https://www.springer.com/journal/10846/submission-guidelines) journal and in the guidelines section, the journal ask for a declarations section to be included in the paper.
I don't know how this section should look like since I've never seen one in a paper before, at least I don't recall I did.
anyone have an idea how to go about it maybe some examples should be nice.

Comment: Why not look at other articles in the journal? The declarations asked for seem pretty standard and straightforward to me; the types are in bold below "Declarations" in the link you gave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a set of legal, ethical, and contractual obligations that every scientist is required to abide by. Many journals specifically ask about key aspects of these as a "checklist" to help ensure that the papers that they publish are consistent with these obligations.

In the guidelines that you link to, the declarations align with these categories as follows:

**Legal:**

- *Ethics approval, Consent to participate, Consent for publication:* if you're doing a biomedical study, these are absolutely ethically required and often legally required as well.

**Contractual:**

- *Funding:* Somebody probably paid for this research, and the funder likely included a contractual requirement to acknowledge that funding, often with very specific language.

**Ethical:**

- *Conflicts of interest/Competing interests:* If your paper might have the effect of promoting or defending a company's product, your readers need to know that fact. Think about [smoking research funded by tobacco companies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1497700/).
- *Availability of data and material:* Necessary for open science and reproducibility.
- *Code availability:* Same as for data.
- *Authors' contributions:* This is part of the move from guessing significance by author order into a more organized ["movie credits"](https://casrai.org/credit/) explanation of why people are on the author lists.